# Vue Router HTML5 History mode .htaccess settings for only one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have added Vue.js and Vue Router to only one page of my website. I have read the Vue Router docs https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html but this applies to a SPA. I would like to know the correct configuration of my .htaccess file so that all routes under /Portfolio.php redirect to that page but not pages such as /Contact.php or /index.php. My website is here: https://test.joebaileyphotography.com

I have tried the following configuration to no avail:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^Portfolio\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /Portfolio.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: configure htaccess to rewrite only the paths that are relevant to your vue routes

Comment: Yes, that's my question

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by placing the page I wanted to apply the .htaccess rules to in its own folder